# Calling application.terminate in DB application

Tags: delphi

Does application terminate take care of closing the opened tables and queries (example, if you have all of them on a data module) or must you close them in code one by one ? If you are quitting the application from one form while you have one hidden is it ok to call i.e free this hidden form before application shuts down? Just curious what  application.terminate actually does....

Comment: If you don't know, first ask documentation about [`TApplication.Terminate`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.Terminate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Application.Terminate closes your application in an orderly fashion". This is what the help file states. It is actually the same as hitting the 'X'. When you close the main form, all underlying forms close as well. This is also true for the tables and queries.

Comment: This is only true, if all of them have an owner that takes care of that